# How can I move a file to the current working directory?

Tags: files, directory, mv

How can I move a file within a directory to the current working directory without renaming?

I can mv a file from current working directory to the parent directory without renaming using the shorthand..

```
mv file.file ../
```

To move a file from a directory to the current working directory I've tried..

```
mv directory/file.file /
```

but I get permission denied.

However,

```
mv directory/file.file file.file
```

works but I have to type out the file name and the autocomplete won't work because the file isn't in the current working directory.

Isn't there a shorthand to specify the current working directory?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To move a file to the current directory you (as you correctly surmised) need to indicate which directory to move to.  This is because `mv` will note that the destination is a directory and will not rename the file on the way.  So the...

**Question Is:**

How do I denote the current directory on the command line

**Answer:**

The current working directory is `.` (a single dot)

Answer (score -1):

```bsh
$ ls 
├── foo.txt
├── bar.txt
├── dir
│   ├── foo2.txt
│   └── bar2.txt
└── dir2
```

for move foo2 to the working directory, use

```bsh
mv dir/foo2.txt  .
```

To move bar.txt from the working directory to `dir` you can use another why

```bsh
mv ./bar.txt dir
```

```bsh
├── ../../ parent of parent
│   └── ../ parent
│        └── ./ working directory
└──
```